# Unresolved reference: android in gradle.kts

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to migrate to gradle.dsl but I'm catching this error. How come this file doesn't see android block?

```
apply {
    from("$rootDir/shared_build.gradle")
    plugin("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
}

android {
    namespace = "kz.poedem.analytics"
}

dependencies {

    // Amplitude
    "api"("com.amplitude:analytics-android:1.11.0")

    "implementation"(project(":common"))
}
```

```
e: /Users/azatsabirov/AndroidStudioProjects/Poedem/analytics/build.gradle.kts:6:1: Unresolved reference: android
```

Hopefully you can help me, friends

Comment: You didn't apply android library plugin you can add it like this:
apply("com.android.library")
And kotlin plugin for work with kotlin:
apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")

Comment: I'm also facing same problem for my shared build gradle file. I have applied apply("com.android.library"), but still same problem